# Python Date Gaps In Percentage

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

Assume I have these allocation dates to work for all employees:

> 01-JANUARY-2019 TO  31-JANUARY-2019

Suppose below employee already allocated its dates to work on,it might be sometime work two or more employees working together in same slab like employee A and employee D,

> Employee A : 01-JANUARY-2019 TO 04-JANUARY-2019
>
> Employee B : 22-JANUARY-2019 TO 25-JANUARY-2019
>
> Employee C : 10-JANUARY-2019 TO 20-JANUARY-2019
>
> Employee D : 02-JANUARY-2019 TO 06-JANUARY-2019

I have tried to find out one by one dates from range then compare with slab but it will take a bit more time n complex,

> from datetime import timedelta, date
>
> def daterange(date1, date2):

```
 for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):

     yield date1 + timedelta(n)
```

So expected result would be :

> Total Allocation :  01 January to 31 January == 31 Days
>
> Allocated Employee in Between Dates :

- Employee A / Employee D : 01 January to 06 January = 6 Days
- Employee C : 10 January to 20 January = 11 Days
- Employee B : 22 January to 25 January = 4 Days

> So Final Gap would expect as result = 31 Days - (6 + 11 + 4) = 10 DAYS

Answer (score 0):

This would be what you're expecting

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

work_days = (datetime(day=31, month=1, year=2019) - datetime(day=1, month=1, year=2019)).days
empl_a = (datetime(day=1, month=1, year=2019), datetime(day=4, month=1, year=2019))
empl_b = (datetime(day=22, month=1, year=2019), datetime(day=25, month=1, year=2019))
empl_c = (datetime(day=10, month=1, year=2019), datetime(day=20, month=1, year=2019))
empl_d = (datetime(day=2, month=1, year=2019), datetime(day=6, month=1, year=2019))

total = sum((date2 - date1).days for date1, date2 in (empl_a, empl_b, empl_c, empl_d))
print(work_days - total)
```

Comment: Sorry ! actually you see employee A : 01 to 4 JAN and Employee D:  2 To 6 Jan so its overlapping so total independent working dates : 01 to 6 Jan , i think here we are considering a individual date different, isn't it ?

Comment: Yet it's not considering overlaps :/

Comment: You want overlaps to be subtracted from the final result?

Comment: yes exactly, you see in example, i have saw you that overlapping days count of employee A + D = 6 days, not 9 days.

Comment: Actually we have to consider only whats days are not allocated in between 01 JAN to 31 January. thats our goal.